# SharePoint 2007 list item approval workflow - displaying approver comments in a list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I'm working on a SharePoint 2007 workflow to develop a user feedback process as follows:

1. User adds a new item to a list (i.e. comments, issues, concerns, etc.)
2. Management is then notified of the new item by e-mail and prompted to respond. The response has two elements: first, outright approval or rejection. Second, providing a comment/answer to the the user concern.
3. If approved, the new item displays in the list
   *3a. The comments ALSO display in the list, in their own column.*

I have Content Approval enabled on this list. I've been able to successfully complete all steps except the very last. How can I get the actual approver comments to display in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Add a multiline text field that allows to append only, not edit, and make you wrokflow to comments there. That should be the most simple solution.